# getting blank pdf file attachment using phpmailer and mpdf

Tags: php, phpmailer, mpdf

I'm using mPDF to generate PDF's when a button is clicked and the i save them inside a folder. I am looking for a way to add the PDF to an attachment using PHPmailer. Here is what I've tried:

```
$dir =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$pdfexist = $dir."/classes/pdf/feestructure_".$student['rollno'].".pdf";
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->From="xyz@abc.com";
        $mail->FromName="xyz";
        $mail->addAddress("xyz@abc.com");
        //echo $email."<br/>";
        $mail->addAddress("xyz@abc.com");
        $mail->addAddress("xyz@abc.com");
        $mail->Subject = 'XYZ';

       $pdfstring = $pdfexist;
       $mail->AddStringAttachment($pdfstring, "feestructure_".$roll.".pdf", $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

The size of my generated pdf is 13k but its showing 1 k in mail attachment.help me guys.

Here is the output from mpdf:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents("$dir/feestructure_pdf.php?rollno=$rollno"));    
          $pdfname="feestructure_".$rollno.".pdf";   
          $mpdf->Output("classes/pdf/".$pdfname,"F");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$pdfexists` / `$pdfstring` variable contains a file path, not binary PDF data, so you should be using `AddAttachment()`, not `AddstringAttachment()`. AddAttachment attaches files (like your PDF), AddStringAttachment attaches strings, like what you might get back from a web call or a database.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($pdfstring, "feestructure_".$roll.".pdf", $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

Comment: thanks a  lot for ur answer it was helpful though i have done it through curl() coz my pdf generation page and this page were seperate.